# Garage door doesn’t close all the way

Tags: doors, garage

[image]

Hi, my garage door doesn’t seem to close all the way by a 2-4 inches.  I just had the garage remodeled and wanted to see how I can fix this before dirt starts going inside the garage.  I thought I’ll ask here if anyone had this issue and how would you recommend to fix it before I call a garage repairman.

Thanks

[image]

Thank you all. The remodel work did not include touching the garage door, this must have been done by the previous owner. I’ll work on adjusting the latches later this week as it’s clearly higher than it should be. However, even pushing the door down with my leg as if the latches were higher, I have noticed that the right side still remains open and doesn’t close all the way. It appears the blocker/item on the top right is preventing the door from closing all the way. Does anyone have any idea on what purpose that metal thing serves and if I can unscrew it and take it out.

Comment: I can't tell from the picture but it looks like the two catches for the door latch are too high. If you turn the handle while lowering the door can you get it lower?

Comment: I see wires.  Are there limit-of-travel detectors for the door?  Also, if you disconnect the door from the power opener, does the door travel freely the entire range?  If it is mechanically binding without the opener, that must be fixed first!

Comment: I don't see a power opener there, this appears to be a manual door.

Comment: if the latch is not working check the tracks for debris and misplaced tools. if it is Tmartin probably has the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This would be better as a comment, but I don't have enough rep to do that. When your garage was remodeled, was the garage door taken off? Looking at the latches that @beswald mentioned, it looks like the door was removed in segments, and the segment with the latches was reinstalled upside down. The latches appear to be below center in that section.

You can consider moving the latches higher in that segment or taking that segment out and flipping it over.

Remember that the tension in the springs can be dangerous. If you are wanting to try to flip the one segment over, I'd suggest using vise grips or locking pliers above the bottom wheel to keep the lower section secured. You also need to keep the upper sections from zipping up the track as well, so as I think more about this, I'd call a garage door repairman.

**Edit** I didn't notice the block on the upper right in the first picture. My guess is that is a "step" that should be on the inside of the bottom section of the door, normally installed so you could step on it to close the door tightly while you lock it. It looks more and more like the door was reinstalled with the sections moved around. I'd hire a garage door company to come out and reinstall it correctly simply because I don't like to mess with the tension springs.

Comment: Excellent theory. That would totally explain the effect; the latches are engaging into the slots on the track too soon because the slots are in a fixed place, but with that panel being upside down and off center, it latches in too soon.